# Checking limits of own pow function in C?

Tags: c, function, testing, pow

So I have am trying to implement my own pow function. To make things somewhat simpler I am allowed to use type int for the exponent. So the code is working...mostly. I have a file called xmath.c in which I implement my pow function and another test.c to test the limits. The only case in which it's not working is for `pow(-111, INT_MAX)`. How could I improve my code ? Also tell me if I should post the test.c code as well. `xfabs` is another function that I had to implement on my own instead of using `fabs`.

Forgot to include xfabs in my post:

```
#define xfabs(x) (((x) > 0) ? (x) : (-(x)))

#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <float.h>
#include "xmath.h"

double xpow(double x, int y)
{
    errno = 0;
    double product = 1;
    double prod = 1;
    int i;

    if (y == 0) {
        return 1.0;
    } else if (x == 0 && y < 0) {
        errno = EDOM;
        return 0.0;
    }

    if (xfabs(x) >= 1) {
        if (y > 0) {
            for (i = 0; i < y; i++) {
                if (xfabs(product) > DBL_MAX / xfabs(x)) {
                        errno = ERANGE;
                        return HUGE_VAL;
                    }
                    product *= x;
                }
            return product;
        } else if (y < 0) {
            for (i = 0; i > y; i--) {
                if (xfabs(product) < DBL_MIN / xfabs(x)) {
                    errno = ERANGE;
                    return -0.0;
                }
                product *= 1 / x;
            }
            return product;
        }

    } else if (xfabs(x) < 1) {
        if (y > 0) {
            for (i = 0; i < y; i++) {
                if (xfabs(prod) < DBL_MIN / xfabs(x)) {
                    errno = ERANGE;
                    return +0.0;
                }
                prod *= x;
            }
            return prod;
        } else if (y < 0) {
            for (i = 0; i > y; i--) {
                if (xfabs(prod) < DBL_MAX / xfabs(x)) {
                    errno = ERANGE;
                    return -HUGE_VAL;
                }
                prod *= 1 / x;
            }
            return prod;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the test function. Also I am creating an object file for xmath.c which I use in test.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <float.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <limits.h>

#include "xmath.h"

void xpow_tests(void)
{
    printf("XPOW TESTS (SUCCESS == 1 / FAILURE == 0)\n");
    printf("=================================================\n");
    printf("Test (xpow(2, 5)): \t\t%i\t", xpow(2, 5) == pow(2, 5));
    xpow(2, 5);
    printf("errno: %i\n", errno);
    printf("Test (xpow(-2, -4)): \t\t%i\t", xpow(-2, -4) == pow(-2, -4));
    xpow(-2, -4);
    printf("errno: %i\n", errno);
    printf("Test (xpow(1, 15)): \t\t%i\t", xpow(1, 15) == pow(1, 15));
    xpow(1, 15);
    printf("errno: %i\n", errno);
    printf("Test (xpow(-4, 414)): \t\t%i\t", xpow(-4, 414) == pow(-4, 414));
    xpow(-4, 414);
    printf("errno: %i\n", errno);
    printf("Test (xpow(-5, 303)): \t\t%i\t", xpow(-5, 303) == pow(-5, 303));
    xpow(-5, 303);
    printf("errno: %i\n", errno);
    printf("Test (xpow(0, -3)): \t\t%i\t", xpow(0, -3) == 0);
    xpow(0, -3);
    printf("errno: %i\n", errno);
    printf("Test (xpow(1.0e-10, 100)): \t%i\t", xpow(1.0e-10, 100) == pow(1.0e-10, 100));
    xpow(1.0e-10, 100);
    printf("errno: %i\n", errno);
    printf("Test (xpow(-1.0e-10, 101)): \t%i\t", xpow(-1.0e-10, 101) == pow(-1.0e-10, 101));
    xpow(-1.0e-10, 101);
    printf("errno: %i\n", errno);
    printf("Test (xpow(-111, INT_MAX)): \t%i\t", xpow(-111, INT_MAX) == pow(-111, INT_MAX));
    xpow(-111, INT_MAX);
    printf("errno: %i\n", errno);
    printf("Test (xpow(-111, INT_MAX-1)): \t%i\t", xpow(-111, INT_MAX-1) == pow(-111, INT_MAX-1));
    xpow(-111, INT_MAX-1);
    printf("errno: %i\n", errno);
    printf("Test (xpow(-111, -INT_MAX)): \t%i\t", xpow(-111, -INT_MAX) == pow(-111, -INT_MAX));
    xpow(-111, -INT_MAX);
    printf("errno: %i\n", errno);
    printf("Test (xpow(-111, -INT_MAX+1)): \t%i\t", xpow(-111, -INT_MAX+1) == pow(-111, -INT_MAX+1));
    xpow(-111, -INT_MAX+1);
    printf("errno: %i\n", errno);
    printf("=================================================\n");
    printf("errno (EDOM: %i / ERANGE: %i)\n\n", EDOM, ERANGE);
}

int main(void)
{
    xpow_tests();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "Not working" means what? Please give us something concrete to build on here.

Comment: So the function does not calculate at all for pow(-111, INT_MAX) meaning my function xpow does not give any result for those values or they are not equal to the values from the real pow function..does that help ?

Comment: It's going to give a `double` result regardless. Do you have a test case for this code are you just hammering at it randomly? Test-driven development, where you have well-defined tests for all your boundary conditions, is key here.

Comment: yeah i will edit the test function...and the function is a bit complicated i know...i don't know how to improve it though because i'm still learning...

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of overflow?  And what maximum size that a double could possibly represent accurately?  I'd suggest starting at a lower exponent and increasing it until your result is garbage, then step through in a debugger to determine why.

Comment: yeah that's what I am trying to test for with DBL_MAX and DBL_MIN... I have to test for overflow and underflow so if the value is too big to be represented as a double or too small so it's basically 0 but still positive or almost 0 but negative

Comment: I guess the problem is that y is of type int and then I can't test it for pow(-111, INT_MAX) because then y is exactly the maximum or I'm not sure what is going wrong here...a friend told me i have to somehow test if y is a even number or not ? but i didn't really understand at all what he meant by that or why or how to do it..

Comment: so I am testing if my function xpow give the same values as the real pow function and in almost every case I test it does. Exept for xpow(-111, INT_MAX) which is to the same as pow(-111, INT_MAX) my own xpow function gives me 1.#INF00 I am surprized it works for xpow(-111, -INT_MAX)

Comment: Code is incomplete the xfabs function is missing and could be the culprit, unlikely, but please include this function in the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Caveat:* This isn't a solution to your failing test case per se.

But, I simplified your function a bit--this may help.

And I greatly simplified/enhanced your test case function [using some preprocessor trickery].

However, in addition to your failed test `-111,INT_MAX`, when I ran it here, the `0,-3` test reports failure.

---

Here's the modified source:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <float.h>
#include <limits.h>
//#include "xmath.h"

double
xfabs(double x)
{

    if (x < 0)
        x = -x;

    return x;
}

double
xpow(double x, int y)
{
    errno = 0;
    int i;
    double lim;
    double prod = 1;
    double abs_x;

    if (y == 0)
        return 1.0;
    if ((x == 0) && (y < 0)) {
        errno = EDOM;
        return 0.0;
    }

    abs_x = xfabs(x);

    if (abs_x >= 1) {
        if (y > 0) {
            lim = DBL_MAX / abs_x;
            for (i = 0; i < y; i++) {
                if (xfabs(prod) > lim) {
                    errno = ERANGE;
                    return HUGE_VAL;
                }
                prod *= x;
            }
        }

        if (y < 0) {
            lim = DBL_MIN / abs_x;
            for (i = 0; i > y; i--) {
                if (xfabs(prod) < lim) {
                    errno = ERANGE;
                    return -0.0;
                }
                prod *= 1 / x;
            }
        }

        return prod;
    }

    if (y > 0) {
        lim = DBL_MIN / abs_x;
        for (i = 0; i < y; i++) {
            if (xfabs(prod) < lim) {
                errno = ERANGE;
                return +0.0;
            }
            prod *= x;
        }
    }

    if (y < 0) {
        lim = DBL_MAX / abs_x;
        for (i = 0; i > y; i--) {
            if (xfabs(prod) < lim) {
                errno = ERANGE;
                return -HUGE_VAL;
            }
            prod *= 1 / x;
        }
    }

    return prod;
}

int passcnt = 0;
int failcnt = 0;

void
dotest(const char *name,double x,int y)
{
    int sverr_pow;
    int sverr_xpow;
    double expected;
    double actual;
    int passflg;

    printf("\n");
    printf("%s\n",name);

    errno = 0;
    expected = pow(x,y);
    sverr_pow = errno;

    printf("%.16g (pow)\n",expected);
    if (sverr_pow)
        printf("errno: %d (%s)\n",sverr_pow,strerror(sverr_pow));

    errno = 0;
    actual = xpow(x,y);
    sverr_xpow = errno;

    printf("%.16g (xpow)\n",actual);
    if (sverr_xpow)
        printf("errno: %d (%s)\n",sverr_xpow,strerror(sverr_xpow));

    if ((actual == expected) && (sverr_xpow == sverr_pow))
        passcnt += 1;
    else
        failcnt += 1;

    printf("Result: Value:%s errno:%s\n",
        (actual == expected) ? "PASS" : "FAIL",
        (sverr_xpow == sverr_pow) ? "PASS" : "FAIL");
}

#define TEST(x,y) \
    dotest(#x "," #y,x,y)

void xpow_tests(void)
{
    printf("XPOW TESTS (SUCCESS == 1 / FAILURE == 0)\n");
    printf("=================================================\n");

    TEST(2, 5);
    TEST(-2, -4);
    TEST(1, 15);
    TEST(-4, 414);
    TEST(-5, 303);
    TEST(0, -3);
    TEST(1.0e-10, 100);
    TEST(-1.0e-10, 101);
    TEST(-111, INT_MAX);
    TEST(-111, INT_MAX-1);
    TEST(-111, -INT_MAX);
    TEST(-111, -INT_MAX+1);

    printf("=================================================\n");
    printf("errno (EDOM: %i / ERANGE: %i)\n\n", EDOM, ERANGE);

    printf("PASSED: %d, FAILED: %d\n",passcnt,failcnt);
}

int
main(void)
{
    xpow_tests();
    return 0;
}
```

---

Here's the output of the tests:

```
XPOW TESTS (SUCCESS == 1 / FAILURE == 0)
=================================================

2,5
32 (pow)
32 (xpow)
Result: Value:PASS errno:PASS

-2,-4
0.0625 (pow)
0.0625 (xpow)
Result: Value:PASS errno:PASS

1,15
1 (pow)
1 (xpow)
Result: Value:PASS errno:PASS

-4,414
1.789931494904685e+249 (pow)
1.789931494904685e+249 (xpow)
Result: Value:PASS errno:PASS

-5,303
-6.136366831622158e+211 (pow)
-6.136366831622158e+211 (xpow)
Result: Value:PASS errno:PASS

0,-3
inf (pow)
errno: 34 (Numerical result out of range)
0 (xpow)
errno: 33 (Numerical argument out of domain)
Result: Value:FAIL errno:FAIL

1.0e-10,100
0 (pow)
errno: 34 (Numerical result out of range)
0 (xpow)
errno: 34 (Numerical result out of range)
Result: Value:PASS errno:PASS

-1.0e-10,101
-0 (pow)
errno: 34 (Numerical result out of range)
0 (xpow)
errno: 34 (Numerical result out of range)
Result: Value:PASS errno:PASS

-111,INT_MAX
-inf (pow)
errno: 34 (Numerical result out of range)
inf (xpow)
errno: 34 (Numerical result out of range)
Result: Value:FAIL errno:PASS

-111,INT_MAX-1
inf (pow)
errno: 34 (Numerical result out of range)
inf (xpow)
errno: 34 (Numerical result out of range)
Result: Value:PASS errno:PASS

-111,-INT_MAX
-0 (pow)
errno: 34 (Numerical result out of range)
-0 (xpow)
errno: 34 (Numerical result out of range)
Result: Value:PASS errno:PASS

-111,-INT_MAX+1
0 (pow)
errno: 34 (Numerical result out of range)
-0 (xpow)
errno: 34 (Numerical result out of range)
Result: Value:PASS errno:PASS
=================================================
errno (EDOM: 33 / ERANGE: 34)

PASSED: 10, FAILED: 2
```

Comment: yes the xpow(0, -3) should return an error because you can't calculate 0 at the power of negative numbers. Also thanks for cleaning up my code a bit.

Comment: You're welcome. I had thought about comparing `errno` values as well, so I've edited the code to include that as part of test pass. The bulk of your function logic seems to produce good results, so I think you're very close.

Comment: BTW, `TEST(0,-1)` should be added. It [currently] produces a mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

For correctness, you should add the special case `if (y == 0 && x == 0) { errno = EDOM;`

You have a lot of duplicated code. You should add `if(y<0) return 1.0/xpow(x, -y);` to get rid of those.

The code is also pretty inefficient with longer loops than necessary. You should utilize that x^y=(x^(y/2))^2. Doing that recursively would save a lot of iterations. Of course, you have to treat odd numbers with a little addon.

Comment: I was thinking about adding a case for x && y = 0 but 0 at the power of 0 should be 1 and I have a case for which y = 0 that already returns 1. I know the code is pretty messy and inneficient but i first wanted to make it work. I will try to improve it if I can.

Comment: @Saty Why should it be 1? Mathematically 0^0 is not defined.

Comment: I think the exercise is to create `xpow` so that it exactly replicates `pow`. And, `pow(0,0)` returns `1`

Comment: @CraigEstey yes that is correct.  idk google says it's 1. Also i have since thought about how i could implement the code and improve it. Basically i will try to make everything with a single loop not 4 and i need to check if y so the exponent is even or odd. If x is negative for example but y is even, the result will be HUGE_VAL positive, but if x is negative and y is odd, then it will be negative so -HUGE_VAL. This will also solve the issue for xpow(-111, INT_MAX)

Comment: @Saty If that's the reason it makes sense. The reason it is undefined in mathematics is that 0^x=0 and x^0=1, and you cannot satisfy both for 0^0.